# Unable to call rest endpoint with non-443 port with a httpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core-3.1

Trying to call a simple rest point which is run on a different port(non-443) through a console app.
This is my code.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    string url = "https://myrestapi.company.com:9443/api/healthcheck";
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
    {
        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(apiResponse);
    }
}
```

I tried to run it through Visual Studio and also directly running the exe, but I get an error:

```
<big>Access Denied (connect_method_denied)</big>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your request attempted a CONNECT to a port "9443" that is not permitted by default.
</FONT>
This is typically caused by an HTTPS URL that uses a port other then the default of 443.
</FONT>
```

I am running on Windows 10 and VS 2019. How do I fix this?
Note that on the same machine, I can run it through swagger or even a curl from my git bash.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://myrestapi.company.com:9443/api/healthcheck'
```

Comment: It is a rest service hosted on a different machine but within the same network. The service is accessible if I run a curl from the same machine, so I am guessing I am missing something in my httpClient which would let me access it.

Comment: have you setup a proxy on your machine ? Curl will bypass the proxy I guess.

Comment: I haven't set any as far as I can tell. Even if there are if was something in Visual Studio, I would imagine running the exe separately would avoid using any proxy if it isn't set at a machine level.

Comment: "It is a rest service hosted on a different machine but within the same network". Sounds like the issue is on your network.

Comment: A curl command or a swagger call from the client machine is working fine. That leads me to believe that I should be able to reach the rest api from my C# code as well. How do I find out if there is a setting that the curl uses that my httpClient object doesn't have or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it was because the url I was hitting was wrong.

I had
https://myrestapi.dev.company.com:9443/api/healthcheck

instead of
https://myrestapi-dev.company.com:9443/api/healthcheck
(Note the - instead of .)

I am not sure why it didn't give me a better error message. Posting it here in case it helps someone else.